# What's the best way to reheat frozen boiled potatoes?

Tags: potatoes, reheating, frozen

We got some imported Papa Amarilla frozen precooked (boiled) potatoes. Probably not many people know about this specific kind of potato, but I was wondering if someone knows how to best reheat any kind of potato that was first boiled, then frozen. Is heating them in a pot with water best? What about using a steamer? The microwave?

Answer (score 3):

When I have left-over boiled potatoes, I always freeze them and when I have enough frozen potatoes, I pour them (still frozen) into an oven-proof dish, spray some olive oil over them, throw in a branch or 2 of fresh rosemary and put them into the cold oven and then set it to 150°C and let them heat up that way.  (until the tip of a fork pushed into the middle of the largest potato comes out hot.)

*Then you'll have perfect par-boiled baked potatoes!*

Boiling or microwaving them makes them too soggy for my taste...

Comment: I agree that boiling isn't a good option, microwaving should be ok though. If you have time baking is definitely best.